# Establish MySQL database connection from netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, mysql

I am doing a project in javafx using netbeans 7.4. I need to establish a connection with MySQL database. What are the steps for that ?

Comment: What is the link with JavaFX? First link on google: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Comment: @assylias Thanks bro...that link was helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Java project with netbeans i use this(local database):

```
 String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Database";

    try{Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); //... set the driver  
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password");
     stmt = con.createStatement();
     System.out.println("Connected!");
    }catch(Exception q){System.out.println("Not connected!");
```

The url can be found in database property, the driver too

Comment: What is the braces of Class.forName();

Comment: is the name of the driver that the mysql database use in my project.
You can fin it in database properties

Comment: Thanks. I will contact you in case of further doubts.